# Table order ascending or descending when heading is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have an HTML table that is populated by a Javascript Array, and what I'm trying to do is make it so that when ever "Depth" is clicked it will sort it either Ascending or Descending.

Here is the table I have an the function:

```
var lakeData = [
 {
   "Month": "1959-01",
   "LakeErieLevels": 12.296
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-02",
   "LakeErieLevels": 13.131
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-03",
   "LakeErieLevels": 13.966
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-04",
   "LakeErieLevels": 15.028
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-05",
   "LakeErieLevels": 15.844
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-06",
   "LakeErieLevels": 15.769
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-07",
   "LakeErieLevels": 15.237
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-08",
   "LakeErieLevels": 14.801
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-09",
   "LakeErieLevels": 14.137
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-10",
   "LakeErieLevels": 13.89
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-11",
   "LakeErieLevels": 13.416
 },
 {
   "Month": "1959-12",
   "LakeErieLevels": 13.871
 }
];

var lakes = document.getElementById("lake");

lakeData.forEach(l => {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var d = tr.insertCell(0);
  d.innerHTML = l.Month;
  var de = tr.insertCell(1);
  de.innerHTML = l.LakeErieLevels;
  lakes.appendChild(tr);
});
```

And here's the table in HTML:

```
<table id="lake">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Depth</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
 </table>
```

And again, what I've been trying to do is when the "Depth" heading is clicked, it will sort the table by depth ascending, and if it's clicked again, it will sort it descending.

Comment: You're gonna want to post any code you've tried to show that you've at least made attempts to do this on your own without the expectation that someone here will just write the code for you.  Otherwise you'll be downvoted and most likely this question will be closed.

Comment: Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmhuaedj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can sort the data when the `th` is clicked:

```
//probably better to give your th element an id
//  and syle cursor:poiter
document.querySelectorAll("#lake th")[1].addEventListener(
  "click"
  ,(direction=>event=>{
    direction = direction * -1;
    lakeData.sort(
      (a,b)=>
        (a.LakeErieLevels>b.LakeErieLevels)
          ? direction
          : (a.LakeErieLevels<b.LakeErieLevels)
            ? direction * -1
            : 0
    );
    //redo your table with lakeData
  })(-1)
)
```